# Помогите исправить регуярку, очень срочно

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Вот условие: Текст находится в текстовом файле, имеющий структуру «Фамилия И.О. - $оклад». Вывести на экран фамилия всех лиц, чей оклад превышает $9000. Вот мои наработки, буду очень благодарен, это задание обязательно надо с помощью регулярок.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Regex regex = new Regex(@"^([А-Я][а-я]+)\s+([А-Я])\.\s*([А-Я])\.\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)$");
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("input.txt", Encoding.GetEncoding(1251)))

            {
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string s = reader.ReadLine();
                    Match match = regex.Match(s);
                    if (match.Success && int.Parse(match.Groups[4].Value) > 9000)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Comment: А что за вторая группа цифр в регулярке? И дефис из описания структуры нигде не ищется

Comment: Ну вот это и нужно исправить, я в них вообще не понимаю.

Comment: Базовые знания по регуляркам изучаются за 15 минут. А ничего сверх этого в задании и не нужно.

Comment: Если вы решили проблему с помощью регулярок, то теперь у вас две проблемы (с)

Comment: Вы хотите найти совпадения, где оклад больше 9К, без использования `int.Parse(match.Groups[4].Value) > 9000`?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот так. Мы считаем, что число больше 9000 в двух случаях: 9ddd или ddddd и больше

```
^([А-Я][а-я]+)\s+([А-Я])\.\s*([А-Я])\.\s+-\s+(9\d\d\d$|\d{4,}$)
```